# Filter ComboBox when typing first letters?

Tags: c#, wpf

Is it possible to filter results of a ComboBox when the user types the first few letters into a TextBox?

I've tried googling, cant seem to find it. Not sure if I'm looking for the wrong thing, but figured I've had some good help on here so far :)

Comment: Windows Forms / WPF ...???

Comment: WPF, WinForms, ASP.NET: yes, it's possible.

Comment: WPF, sorry, forgot about that

Comment: fyi http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is a WPF Incremental Combo Box

See this:

Automatically Filtering a ComboBox in WPF

http://weblogs.asp.net/okloeten/archive/2007/11/12/5088649.aspx

Comment: actually you can just use any List<T> as a Itemsource and the filtering will occur automatically